# Domain Alias for Azure Databases

Tags: sql-server, security, azure-sql-database

I have 3 databases on Azure's cloud, all with domains names such as `xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net`.

Would it be a bad idea to create domain name aliases for all 3, things such as:

`database.domain.com`

`staging.database.domain.com`

`test.database.domain.com`

The only issue I could come up with was that there could be a security risk involved, easily guessable domain names for the databases, but I'm not sure if that's even a risk with Azure SQL databases?

Comment: Names in my opinion are not in any way related to security, except possibly through obscurity however security-by-obscurity is not security at all.

Comment: As an FYI, and perhaps you are already aware, is that in the new portal, you can create friendly names for your database.  So no more xhdlsdkd.database.windows.net : )

Comment: @JosephIdziorek Oh cool, I hadn't noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek Trying to have easy-to-remember host names